# Distributivity of AND/OR in propositional algebra?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

How can I rewrite something like (B AND A) OR (C AND NOT(A))? I understand that if I have something like (B AND A) OR (C AND A), I can rewrite it as A AND (B OR C), but I'm not sure what to do if one of them is negated.

Comment: You might want to use the logical symbols $\land$ (AND), $\lor$ (OR), $\neg$ (NOT) to make your question more readable. As for your the answer, there is not really a shorter way to write as you did.

Answer (score 2):

There's no standard notation in logic that will let you write this formula any simpler.

Many *programming languages* have an [if-then-else operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming)#If.E2.80.93then.E2.80.93else_expressions) that would allow you to write something like `if A then B else C` or `A ? B : C`, and in *digital logic* the functionality is that of a basic 2-way [multiplexer gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer).

But there is no tradition for working with such connectives in mathematical logic.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to mention that the common approach to simplify boolean expressions is the [Karnaugh Map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map), and there are automated tools that could help you with it, such as [boolean-algebra.com](https://www.boolean-algebra.com/). If you plug your expression into it (the notation is $BA+C\overline{A}$), you'll see that it generates the following Karnaugh Map, which (as the other answer mentioned) cannot be further simplified with the regular Boolean operations:

[image: K map of the expression in the question]